# List all relations from a module in SICStus Prolog

Tags: module, prolog, sicstus-prolog

Is there any way to get the list of all relations defined in a loaded module in SICStus Prolog interpreter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the current_predicate/1 built_in predicate:

```
findall(Predicate, current_predicate(Module:Predicate), L)
```